# Difficulty understanding FLOPS in this scenario

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, flops

Given FLOPS are the floating point operations per second, would that not be dependent on the power of the machine rather than the model and how many parameters it has? What am I missing here? Screenshot is from "EfficientNet: Rethinking Model Scaling for Convolutional Neural Networks". Thanks.

[image: EfficientNet FLOPS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hardware manufacturers [specify](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-modules) FLOPS as the performance metric. On the other hand, you can calculate approximate FLOPs value for your model, for regular (not depthwise) convolutional layer it would be (according to [this](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1039#issuecomment-415460461)):

[image: formula]

where 2 is for two different types of instructions: multiplying and accumulating.

You need to keep in mind that low FLOPS value do not automatically provide high performance.

Comment: I see, so should that be FLOPs (total operations) in the final column rather than FLOPS (total operations per second). And would it then mean the FLOPs for a single pass of the CNN? Thanks

Comment: @numunu Yep you are right, FLOPS for hardware and FLOPs for neural net forward pass. Edited that in the answer